# repeat the view code depending on the observableArray length? - knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

Need help to create a table depending on the observableArray length.

The observableArray - **Pages** - is an array with numbers.
Now i want to create a table row with 10 numbers in each row. for the 11th element, i have to insert from a new row. So a new row has to be created after 10 elements.

So my table should be like:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10

11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20

21  22  23
```

The view model code is:

```
function Pagination() {

    var self = this;
    self.TotalPageCount = ko.observable("23");
    self.Pages = ko.observableArray(['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10',
                    '11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20',
                                    '21','22','23' ]);

};
```

The view code:

```
<table id="pagerTable">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Pages.length / 10"> 
        <tr>  <!-- have to create table row for every 10 elements  -->
           <td>
                <a data-bind="attr:{ 'id': $index }, text: $data " ></a> 
           </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Can anyone help me with a solution? JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ondacinaynakalkur/w928F/1/

The fiddle link just prints the entire array content. I want the array content to be displayed in a table with 10 elements in each row:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10

11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20

21  22  23
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shubh0602/apdJc/)

The solution which I have currently for you is break it into Chunk of Arrays and display it .

First Break it into chunks, look into [split-array-into-chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks). Thanks to `@dentaku`

```
//Convert your table to Chunk of Arrays
function TableModel(pages) {

    var longArray = pages;
    var smallerArrays = []; // will contain the sub-arrays of 10 elements each
    var arraySize = 10;
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.ceil(longArray.length / arraySize); i++) {
        smallerArrays.push(longArray.slice(i * arraySize, i * arraySize + arraySize));
    }
    return smallerArrays;
}
```

Then lets change you HTML code to below:-

```
<table id="pagerTable" data-bind="foreach: Tables">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <!-- have to create table row for every 10 elements -->
            <td> <a data-bind="attr:{ 'id': $index }, text: $data "></a> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You View Model would look like :-

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.TotalPageCount = ko.observable("23");
    this.Pages = ko.observableArray(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10',
        '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20',
        '21', '22', '23']);
    this.Tables = TableModel(this.Pages());
    console.log(this);
}
```

You can find a [Working Version Here](http://jsfiddle.net/shubh0602/apdJc/)

Comment: Hi, I tried with the fiddle example. I have modified the jsfiddle according to my requirement. Now, i have **Tables** array with 3 rows, where each row has 10 items. How to loop through it and dislay the content such that i have 10 columns for 10 items in each row of the array. So the resultant table should have 3 rows, and 10 columns. Can anyone help me by modifying the jsfiddle?    Thanks!

Comment: Finally got it working. here is the updated jsfiddle for the same: http://jsfiddle.net/apdJc/23/